# Library methods with date of introduction

Tags: data-request, computing

I am looking for a dataset containing a list of libraries with the methods they contain and the date or library version when each method was introduced/changed.

Example: the method [`pandas.io.sql.read_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.12.0/generated/pandas.io.sql.read_sql.html) in the [pandas library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_(software)) was introduced in `pandas 0.12.0` (release date: 2013-07-24).